# S3 stop uploading files iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 application, one in swift and the other in objective-c, I'm using cognito to authenticate with s3 but the last days this feature stop working I down know why, the console of my application say "request timed out" but I don't change anything. the application start uploading but always stops in 39% or 14% and freeze the upload, this is my code:

App delegate:

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,
        identityPoolId:poolId)
    AWSLogger.defaultLogger().logLevel = .Verbose

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.SAEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

PhotoViewController

```
 let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
 uploadRequest.bucket = "bucket"
 uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.PublicRead
 uploadRequest.key = "\(self.userLogin.customer_subdomain)/photos/\(imageName)"
 uploadRequest.contentType = "image/png"
 uploadRequest.body = url

 uploadRequest.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64,  totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) -> Void in
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
         self.updateLabel(totalBytesSent,totalBytesExpectedToSend: totalBytesExpectedToSend)
     })
 }

 AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager().upload(uploadRequest).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
     if (task.error != nil) {
         //failed
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
             let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Error al intentar subir el archivo", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
             refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
             self.presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
         print(task.error!)
     } else {
         let dic=["file":"\(self.userLogin.customer_subdomain)/photos/\(imageName)"]
         let jsonData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dic, options: [])
         let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String

         let con:URLConnection
         con=URLConnection.init()
         con.delegate=self
         let headers=["X-Auth-Token":self.userLogin.api_token]
         con.connect(self.userLogin.customer_url+"/rest/activities/\(self.activity.id)/photos",method:"POST",json: jsonString, headers: headers)
         self.imgName = "\(self.userLogin.customer_subdomain)/photos/\(imageName)"               
     }
     return nil
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was the datetime of the device, always need to be the correct hour